# UItableview variable section header height and content

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Does anyone know how to go about creating a UITableView with variable height section headers and content, similar to the Facebook iPhone app?

So I want some headers to have text (e.g. Favorites, Apps, etc...). But some section headers I just want no text but rather be 5 pixel tall separator (e.g. like in the Facebook Messenger app separator).

Example:

```
FAVORITES <-- Header:
 fav1
 fav2
 fav3

APPS   <-- Header: this is all apps header
 app1  <-- these are the most used apps
 app2
=====  <-- Header: this is a header with no text (see Facebook Messenger)
 app3  <-- apps not used in a long time
 app4

FRIENDS <-- Header:
 Sam
 Tina
```

So I need dynamic content for the section headers. The sections need to be in a certain order everytime. Finally, the section headers need to be of certain height.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to reference the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource docs.

Specifically these two methods:

[– tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a)

and

[- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a)